# Authenticate with Firebase on iOS Using a Custom Authentication System

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Microsoft Graph to Authenticate the users to my app ([following this iOS tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-ios)) and I would like to use Firebase as my DB.

I was trying to do as it says in [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/custom-auth), however, I am not sure about the part that says:

> "The new service account's public/private key pair is automatically saved on your computer. Copy this file to your authentication server."

Where should I copy this JSON file to?